# MediaFire forbidden error when adding <script... lines in code sample

Tags: shared-hosting

I am trying to add a code sample to a self hosted mediawiki page, but every time I try to add this and save the page I get a Forbidden error stating "You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.".

The code sample is:

```
 <script src="jquery/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

 <script src="jquery/placeholder/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/uniform/uniform.default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <script src="jquery/uniform/jquery.uniform.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

   $(function(){
     $("input, textarea, select, button").uniform();
  });

   $(function() {
   // Invoke the plugin
     $('input, textarea').placeholder();
   });
 </script>
```

If I remove the `<script...` and `<link...` lines it saves the page and displays correctly.  Any ideas how I can overcome this error?

Cheers

Steve

Comment: Are you using some sort of extension to display the code? How exactly are you trying to add it?

Comment: No matter how I tried to display the code it was giving me the Forbidden error.  Seems it was a security setting on my shared host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

This was a security setting on my shared host.  A quick support email sorted it out.